# Why am I getting this error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Google Map v2 in Tabs.

**Here is layout file of activity.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#333333" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/registrationLayout" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> I get this error when I transfer my project to another PC. I have imported GooglePlayService for GoogleMap V2 and Facebook SDK 3.5.2 in my work space.

**Here is the java code**

```
public class NearMe extends FragmentActivity {

GpsProvider gpsProvider;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
double lat;
double lng;
JsonParser jparser;
String latString, longString, titleString, dis, distanceString,
        stationIdString, colorNameString;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dockitstationsArrayList,
        stationidArrayList;
BitmapDescriptor bitmapMarker;
NetworkHelper nh;
AlertDialogManager alertDialogManager = new AlertDialogManager();
// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
HashMap<String, String> markershashmap = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Setting View for Screen
    setContentView(R.layout.near_me);

    dockitstationsArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    markershashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            try {
                String distance[] = marker.getSnippet().split(" - ");
                String distanceString = distance[0];
                String idString = marker.getId();
                String stationid = markershashmap.get(idString);
                Message mesg = new Message();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("stationId", stationid);
                b.putString("distance", distanceString);
                mesg.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(mesg);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();

        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        b1.putString("stationId", b.getString("stationId"));
        b1.putString("distance", b.getString("distance"));

        Intent dockitdetailsIntent = new Intent(getParent(),
                DockItStationDetails.class);
        dockitdetailsIntent.putExtras(b1);

        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();

        parentActivity.startChildActivity("Dock It Details",
                dockitdetailsIntent);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
    nh = new NetworkHelper(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = nh.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alertDialogManager.showInfoAlertDialog(NearMe.this.getParent(),
                "Please connect to working internet connection");
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }
    gpsProvider = new GpsProvider(this.getParent());

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gpsProvider.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gpsProvider.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gpsProvider.getLongitude();

        // \n is for new line

        /*
         * Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
         * "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude,
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         */

        new LoadNearByDockITStations().execute(String.valueOf(latitude),
                String.valueOf(longitude));
    } else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS in settings
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this.getParent());

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        // Setting Gravity to Center
        AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.show();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        TextView messageText = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // Showing Alert Message
        dialog.show();

    }
}

private class LoadNearByDockITStations extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String res, status;
    JSONArray resultJsonArray;
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String lat = arg0[0];
        String lng = arg0[1];
        jparser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = jparser
                .makeHttpRequest(Utility.GETDOCKITLIST + "?latitude=" + lat
                        + "&longitude=" + lng + "&klm=20");
        try {

            // /Getting array of Events.......
            if (jsonObject.getJSONArray(Utility.STATIONS) != null) {

                res = jsonObject.getString(Utility.SUCCESS);

                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                    resultJsonArray = jsonObject
                            .getJSONArray(Utility.STATIONS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        latString = c.getString(Utility.LAT);
                        longString = c.getString(Utility.LONG);
                        titleString = c.getString(Utility.TITLE);

                        distanceString = c.getString(Utility.DISTANCE);

                        stationIdString = c.getString(Utility.STATION_ID);
                        colorNameString = c.getString(Utility.COLOR_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                        // value
                        map.put(Utility.LAT, latString);
                        map.put(Utility.LONG, longString);
                        map.put(Utility.TITLE, titleString);
                        map.put(Utility.DISTANCE, distanceString);
                        // map.put(Utility.DISTANCE, distanceString);

                        map.put(Utility.STATION_ID, stationIdString);
                        map.put(Utility.COLOR_NAME, colorNameString);

                        dockitstationsArrayList.add(map);

                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dockitstationsArrayList.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No Dock It Stations Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             * "Dock It Stations Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */

            googleMap.clear();
            addMarkersToMap();
        }
    }

}

private void addMarkersToMap() {
    ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    LatLng ll = null;
    String distance;

    for (int i = 0; i < dockitstationsArrayList.size(); i++) {

        ll = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(dockitstationsArrayList.get(i)
                .get(Utility.LAT)),
                Double.parseDouble(dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(
                        Utility.LONG)));
        distance = dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(Utility.DISTANCE);

        stationIdString = dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(
                Utility.STATION_ID);
        colorNameString = dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(
                Utility.COLOR_NAME);

        if (colorNameString.equals("Cyan"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.cyan_marker);
        else if (colorNameString.equals("Red"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.red_marker);
        else if (colorNameString.equals("Yellow"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.yellow_marker);
        else if (colorNameString.equals("Blue"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.blue_marker);
        else if (colorNameString.equals("Green"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.green_marker);
        else if (colorNameString.equals("Purple"))
            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.purple_marker);

        MarkerOptions mOption = new MarkerOptions();
        mOption.position(ll);
        mOption.title(dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(Utility.TITLE));
        mOption.anchor(0.0f, 1.0f);
        mOption.snippet(Utility.convertDistance(distance) + "m - Here");
        mOption.icon(bitmapMarker);
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(mOption);
        mMarkers.add(marker);
        String markerkey = marker.getId();
        markershashmap.put(markerkey,
                dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(Utility.STATION_ID));

    }
    // stationidArrayList.add(markers);
    final LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < dockitstationsArrayList.size(); i++) {
        LatLng ll2 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(dockitstationsArrayList
                .get(i).get(Utility.LAT)),
                Double.parseDouble(dockitstationsArrayList.get(i).get(
                        Utility.LONG)));
        bld.include(ll2);
    }
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
            bld.build(), 30));
    // googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
            // Move camera.
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                    bld.build(), 50));
            // Remove listener to prevent position reset on camera move.
            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Here is manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dockit"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<permission
    android:name="com.dockit.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.dockit.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Access Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.AboutUs"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.ListViewDockItStations"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.More"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="twitter"
                android:scheme="app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.NearByDockItTabs"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.NearMeold"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.Registration"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.tabcontroller.TabGroupActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.tabcontroller.TabGroup1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.NearMe"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.tabcontroller.TabGroup2"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.tabcontroller.TabGroup3"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.DockItStationDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAlvDShdumWacdKdHldu3TCAUPyUXId30k" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dockit.RateApplication"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rate_application" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> I capitalize fragment but I got this warning "Invalid tag Fragment should be fragment"

Comment: can you show your java code and what is the minimum version support you are giving?

Comment: Capitalize `Fragment`.

Comment: @Turix nope... `fragment` is correct one...

Comment: @GopalRao Oh, you're right.  Sorry!  (I still think that is very odd given that the class name is `Fragment`.)

Comment: did you transfer your project to another PC? or APK? probably just a project setup issue - like wrong Android build target or something "clean" will fix

Comment: Same project setup is running well in previous system. I have cleaned project and changed setup setting many times, but problem is same. :(